# invalid pointer while using thread in a class with pybind11

Tags: c++, multithreading, pybind11

my original cpp is like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class ENV {
  public:
    std::vector<std::thread> v_td;
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> *p_for_debug;
    ENV(std::vector<std::vector<float>> &v) {
        this->p_for_debug = &v;
        std::cout << this->p_for_debug->size() << std::endl;
        v_td.emplace_back(std::thread(&ENV::td_worker, this));
    }
    
    ~ENV(){
       v_td[0].join();
    }

    void td_worker() {
        std::cout << "td!!" << std::endl; 
        std::cout << this->p_for_debug->size() << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<float> v_{2, 3};
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> v;
    v.emplace_back(v_);
    v.emplace_back(v_);
    auto env=ENV(v);
}
```

and it works fine,its output like this:

```
2
td!!
2
```

then I use pybind11 to call this in python,but I got a invalid pointer,the output is like:

```
2
td!!
2232354356546
```

any advise is appreciated!thank you!

Comment: Why is `p_for_debug` a pointer and not a `std::vector` directly ?

Comment: And anyway `this->p_for_debug = &v;` doesn't look good. It relies on the passed arguments outliving the `ENV` object.

Comment: creating this pointer only to reproduce error

Comment: `std::thread(&ENV::td_worker, this);` this is nonsense, it will immediately call `std::terminate` from thread destructor.

Comment: And about passing by reference in pybind11, it doesn't always work as you think it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012280/how-to-pass-a-vector-by-reference-in-pybind11-c

Answer (score 0):

You address `v_td[0]` but `v_td` is empty vector and no element `[0]` exists. Use `push_back` instead otherwise undefined behavior. When you created thread and failed to store it in `v_td[0]` there is no one to join it and terminate will be called. `v_td[0].join()` in destructor will never work since there will be no thread to join.

```
ENV(std::vector<std::vector<float>> &v) {
        this->p_for_debug = &v;
        std::cout << this->p_for_debug->size() << std::endl;
        v_td[0]=std::thread(&ENV::td_worker, this); 
        //no such element v_td[0] exist in empty vector  
        //yet you invoke thread but who will join it?
  }
```

Another potential problem pointed by @wohlstad where `this` and and referenced vector have different lifetime. Race on vector `v`.

Comment: thanks man,but that's not the key problem.even if I use emplace_back or resize/reserve the v_td,the error is still there

Comment: I just re-edit the code to avoid the problem you said

Answer (score 0):

looks like ( std::vectorstd::vector<float> &v) is somehow unexpected freed by python,so I create a member variable std::vectorstd::vector<float> v_ to get the control of the resource of v,now everything is fine
the code is like:

```
enter code here

#include <torch/extension.h> //contain pybind11
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

class ENV {
  public:
    std::vector<std::thread> v_td;
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> *p_for_debug;
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> v_;
    ENV(){};
    ENV(std::vector<std::vector<float>> &v) {
        this->v_td.resize(1);
        this->v_.swap(v);
        this->p_for_debug = &v_;//this is the key
        std::cout << this->p_for_debug->size() << std::endl;
        this->v_td[0] = std::thread(&ENV::td_worker, this); // create listener task
    }

~ENV() {
    std::cout << "deconstruct!" << std::endl;
    this->v_td[0].join();
};

void td_worker() {
    std::cout << "td!!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << this->p_for_debug->size() << std::endl;
    for (auto v : (*this->p_for_debug)) {
        for (auto x : v) {
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
        }
        
    }
}
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(TORCH_EXTENSION_NAME, m)
{
py::class_<ENV>(m, "ENV")
    .def(py::init<std::vector<std::vector<float>> & >());
}
```

Comment: After swap v_ becomes v but if you use v in some other place you will get empty vector with contents iterators and references of v_ . If that is not a problem simply move v.  What you solved is simply made v_ member of ENV and that's what @wohlstad told you to do to prevent different lifetime.